# Soapui doesn't properly recognized wsdl

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

I have looked over this wsdl many times and can't seem to find the issue. When I try loading the wsdl into soapui i get the following as a request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <parametersReq/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

However that isn't the request i want. None of the parameters in my xsd appears in soapui. What am i doing wrong:

WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>



<wsdl:definitions name="MyService" targetNamespace="http://example.com/myService.wsdl"   xmlns:proto="http://example.com/prototype.xsd"  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/myService.wsdl" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/prototype.xsd" xmlns:proto="http://example.com/prototype.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <xsd:include schemaLocation="prototype.xsd"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="prototypeReqMessage">
        <wsdl:part element="parametersReq" name="proto:PrototypeRequest"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="prototypeRespMessage">
        <wsdl:part element="parametersRes" name="proto:PrototypeResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="MyPortType">
        <wsdl:operation name="invokeProto">
            <wsdl:input name="prototypeReqMessage" message="tns:prototypeReqMessage"/>
            <wsdl:output name="prototypeRespMessage" message="tns:prototypeRespMessage"/>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="MyBinding" type="tns:MyPortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="invokeProto">
            <soap:operation soapAction="urn:MyService" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input name="prototypeReqMessage">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output name="prototypeRespMessage">
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="MyService">
        <wsdl:documentation>My first service</wsdl:documentation>
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:MyBinding" name="MyPort">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/example.com/myService"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://example.com/prototype.xsd" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/prototype.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:temp="http://example.com/temporary.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://example.com/temporary.xsd" schemaLocation="com/example/temporary.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="PrototypeRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element  name="Person" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="Car" type="tns:CarType"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="PrototypeResponse">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="protoResp" type="xsd:string" default="Hello_World"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:complexType name="CarType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Honda" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Toyota" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Ford" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Mercedez" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your WSDL is invalid.

You need to rewrite your message definitions; for e.g.:

```
<wsdl:message name="prototypeReqMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="parametersReq" name="proto:PrototypeRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

Into this:

```
<wsdl:message name="prototypeReqMessage">
    <wsdl:part element="proto:PrototypeRequest" name="parametersReq"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

The *element* attribute in **wsdl:part** must point to the fully qualified name of the element defined by your schema.